# multithreading using 3 threads Java

Tags: java, multithreading, java-threads

I'm trying to create a program which uses threads: thread 1 puts integers into a list, thread 2 filters the even numbers into an even list and thread 3 does the same for odd numbers.

```
public class Manage {

private Object lock = new Object();
private LinkedList<Integer> intStorage = new LinkedList<Integer>();
private LinkedList<Integer> evens = new LinkedList<>();
private LinkedList<Integer> odds = new LinkedList<>();

public void intCollection() throws InterruptedException {

    for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {

        synchronized(lock) {    

            while(i == 20) {    
                lock.wait();
            }

            intStorage.add(i);
            lock.notifyAll();
            System.out.println(intStorage);
        }
        Thread.sleep(100);
    }
}

public void evens() throws InterruptedException {

    for(int i = 0; i < intStorage.size() ; i++) {

        synchronized(lock) {

            if(intStorage.get(i) % 2 != 0) {    
                lock.wait();
            }

            if(intStorage.get(i) % 2 == 0) {
                int j = intStorage.remove(i);
                evens.add(j);
                lock.notifyAll();
            }
            System.out.println(evens);
        }
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

}

public void odds() throws InterruptedException {

    for(int i = 0; i < intStorage.size() ; i++) {

        synchronized(lock) {

            if(intStorage.get(i) % 2 == 0) {    
                lock.wait();
            }

            if(intStorage.get(i) % 2 != 0) {
                int j = intStorage.remove(i);
                odds.add(j);
                lock.notifyAll();
            }
            System.out.println(odds);
        }
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    Manager m = new Manager();

    Thread t1 = new Thread(){
        public void run() {
            try {
                m.intCollection();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    };

    Thread t2 = new Thread(){
        public void run() {
            try {
                m.evens();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    };
    Thread t3 = new Thread(){
        public void run() {
            try {
                m.odds();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    };

    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t3.start(); 

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();

}
}
```

thread 1 runs, however I can't get thread 2 and thread 3 to filter the odds and evens. The program terminates after thread 1 is done.

Comment: @I deleted my answer, edit your code with the correct code and ill take a stab at it.

Comment: "i" will never be equal to 20, so that if statement serves no purpose

Comment: There ya go updated my answer with a complete working example based on your code.

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using `LinkedList` in the first place. There are thread-safe collections in the `java.util.concurrent`package. This is a typical producer - consumer example, and I'd say it would be better to just have a single consumer, delegating to the even /odd handlers.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is you have three threads competing for a lock, but you need the intCollection thread to win the lock first. If any othe thread wins the lock first you will get an out of bounds exception due to this segment:

```
for(int i = 0; i < intStorage.size() ; i++) {

    synchronized(lock) {

        if(intStorage.get(i) % 2 == 0) {
```

even though intStorage is empty it will invoke get(0) and produce an out of bounds exception.

You also did not need the notify and wait calls. I removed those in my solution. I added a check to see if intStorage is empty, thats all there was to it.

Here is the complete answer:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Manager {

    private Object lock = new Object();
    private boolean running = true;
    private LinkedList<Integer> intStorage = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    private LinkedList<Integer> evens = new LinkedList<>();
    private LinkedList<Integer> odds = new LinkedList<>();

    public void intCollection() throws InterruptedException {

        for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {

            synchronized(lock) {
                intStorage.add(i);
                System.out.println("storage: " + intStorage);
            }
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
        running = false;
    }

    public void evens() throws InterruptedException {

        while( (!intStorage.isEmpty()) || running ) {
            synchronized (lock) {
                if(!intStorage.isEmpty()) {
                    if (intStorage.get(0) % 2 == 0) {
                        int j = intStorage.remove(0);
                        evens.add(j);
                    }
                    System.out.println("evens: " + evens);
                }
            }
            Thread.sleep(1);
        }

    }

    public void odds() throws InterruptedException {

        while( (!intStorage.isEmpty()) || running ) {
            synchronized (lock) {
                if(!intStorage.isEmpty()) {
                    if (intStorage.get(0) % 2 != 0) {
                        int j = intStorage.remove(0);
                        odds.add(j);
                    }
                    System.out.println("odds: " + odds);
                }
            }
            Thread.sleep(1);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        //must be final to access
        final Manager m = new Manager();

        Thread t1 = new Thread(){
            public void run() {
                try {
                    m.intCollection();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        };

        Thread t2 = new Thread(){
            public void run() {
                try {
                    m.evens();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        };
        Thread t3 = new Thread(){
            public void run() {
                try {
                    m.odds();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        };

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();

        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        t3.join();

    }
}
```

Comment: make all the other threads check if intStorage is empty within their lock. If it is empty give up the lock and wait

Comment: @JakeBrillet you honestly need to recode the whole thing. That would fix your problem but introduce a new one that your threads never know when they are finished either.

Comment: @JakeBrillet you are also using the lock'sa wait and notify all wrong...

Comment: @JakeBrillet There you go i added a complete working answer for you as closely matching your code as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go...this is working fine : Only thing to notice is change in order of threads join :)

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Manager {

private Object lock = new Object();
private LinkedList<Integer> intStorage = new LinkedList<Integer>();
private LinkedList<Integer> evens = new LinkedList<>();
private LinkedList<Integer> odds = new LinkedList<>();

public void intCollection() throws InterruptedException {

for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    synchronized (lock) {
    while (i == 20) {
        lock.wait();
    }

    intStorage.add(i);
    lock.notifyAll();
    System.out.println(intStorage);
    }
    Thread.sleep(100);
}
}

public void evens() throws InterruptedException {

for (int i = 0; i < intStorage.size(); i++) {
    synchronized (lock) {
    if (intStorage.get(i) % 2 != 0) {
        lock.wait();
    }

    if (intStorage.get(i) % 2 == 0) {
        int j = intStorage.remove(i);
        evens.add(j);
        lock.notifyAll();
    }
    System.out.println("even" + evens);
    }
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}

}

public void odds() throws InterruptedException {

for (int i = 0; i < intStorage.size(); i++) {
    synchronized (lock) {
    if (intStorage.get(i) % 2 == 0) {
        lock.wait();
    }

    if (intStorage.get(i) % 2 != 0) {
        int j = intStorage.remove(i);
        odds.add(j);
        lock.notifyAll();
    }
    System.out.println("odd:" + odds);
    }
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

Manager m = new Manager();

Thread t1 = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
    try {
        m.intCollection();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
    }
};

Thread t2 = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
    try {
        m.evens();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
    }
};
Thread t3 = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
    try {
        m.odds();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
    }
};

t1.start();
t1.join();
t2.start();
t2.join();
t3.start();
t3.join();
}
```

}

Comment: That defeats the purpose of multi threading. All your doing is running one thread, then not starting the other thread until the last one has stopped. The end result is you only have a single thread running at any one time and completely defeats the purpose of using threading at all.

Comment: I am not trying to improve the code here as there are better ways to do this... what i am trying is solve the problem using available code :)

Comment: I understand that. But what you did was effectively make the code worse, not better. See my solution below. It aims to minimally modify the code, still keep the advantages of multithreading, and solve the problem. It does all three of those goals.

Comment: But I just changed the order of join (nothing else) how does this make the code worse ?

Comment: by eliminiting the benefit created by multi-threading. The point of multithreading, is to utilize your cpu's in parallel. You eliminated the parallel nature and thus eliminated all benefit from multithreading.

Comment: Hey but I clarified I am not trying to improve the code as this is not the best way to do it ... Let the person asking the question decide what he/she wants to do ?

Comment: I understand you arent trying to improve it. But prior to your edit the code did run in parallel and did benefit from multithreading. Your edit eliminated that advantage. Thus why I say it is a step backwards, made the code worse. You broke one feature and fixed one bug.